# Moving data from one temporary table to two different tables with relations

Tags: mysql

I have successfully imported data from csv file to one of the temporary table and trying to move the data to two different normalized tables. Current database schema.

```
// Temporary table
temp(id, author, book);

// Destination table
authors(id, name);
books(id, author_id, title)

// Data stored on `temp` table
1, 'Author-A', 'BOOK101'
2, 'Author-A', 'BOOK212'
3, 'Author-B', 'BOOK314'
4, 'Author-B', 'BOOK415'
5, 'Author-B', 'BOOK616'
6, 'Author-C', 'BOOK517'
7, 'Author-C', 'BOOK918'
```

I tried moving data on application layer using php scripts but that's very inefficient and takes too much time. What I am looking is moving data on database level, I have used this query to save the authors name on authors table:-

```
INSERT INTO authors(name) SELECT author FROM temp GROUP BY author
```

But how to save the books for authors with relation maintained?

Answer (score 1):

1. Alter your temp table.

   ALTER TABLE TEMP ADD COLUMN `author_id` INT(10) NULL AFTER `author`;
2. Insert the author values into authors table

   INSERT INTO authors (`name`)
   SELECT DISTINCT author
   FROM TEMP;
   (hope your id is auto increment)
3. Update temp table

   UPDATE temp_table
   INNER JOIN authors a ON temp_table.author = a.name
   SET author_id=a.id
4. Insert the values to your books table.

   INSERT INTO books (`author_id`,`title`)
   SELECT author_id,
          title
   FROM TEMP;

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

if you use mysql than you will define relation using **add index** of your **books** table **author_id** key  and you will store author table primary key into books table author_id field as foreign key.This thing created relation between author table id(primary key) and books table author_id key.